# Does Abe Shinzo defy Japanese cultural taboos when in a foreign or international context?

Tags: international-relations, japan

When in a non-Japanese context, is Abe Shinzo known to defy Japanese cultural taboos that would be inconvenient or problematic? Like the taboos against looking people in the eye; or speaking while walking; or yawning; referring to people directly, among god knows how many more. Is he known to drop these incredibly noticeably behavioural prohibitions? Or does he still respect them while abroad? Out of habit?

Comment: I don't think this sort of question is on-topic on this site. This is basically just a question about the personal life and habits of a politician, and not really about government, policies, or politics. Also see: https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Off topic. This is a not a question about the political activities of a person. The list of "taboos" is fantasy (having spent an evening with Japanese friends and they broke every one of these, except yawning).

Comment: I disagree that this is non-political.  I would assume that it involves his public activities as Prime Minister.  As such, it is is political.